# Do people really do GMRS liscenses

Tags: legal

Sometimes on my Chinese uhf/vhf amateur transceiver, which goes all the way to 520 megahertz, i listen to GMRS/FRS/MURS frequencies. I always hear little kids messing around in the neighborhood on GMRS. Does the FCC really care about this? And what are they going to do about kids buying a Walmart radio and not having a license.

Comment: Voted to close as this is not an amateur radio question.  However, note that there are only about 40 thousand active GMRS licenses, but some estimates indicate in excess of 40 million FRS & GMRS radios have been sold since the introduction of the dual FRM/GMRS radio. So the likely answer to your question is that very, very few people hold licenses to use the radios they own as GMRS radios. The FCC proposal to eliminate the GMRS licensing requirement, proposed in 2010, is still pending.  But obviously they are aware of the situation and are looking at resolution.

Comment: MURS is a whole different animal, since it is VHF.  Here is more info:  https://www.itstactical.com/digicom/comms/the-best-kept-secret-in-radio-communication/ and https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=murs%20radio&cat_id=0 - MURS is license-free, and all MURS radios must be FCC Type-Certified for use in the USA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No license is required for FRS frequencies, and the power restriction is one-half (0.5) watt. As GMRS shares some of these frequencies, "licensed" GMRS users can use up to 5 watts on these. Obviously there is no way to differentiate between these users or power levels just by listening in. The higher GMRS-only frequencies are enforceable, but unless there is blatant jamming or deliberate interference it is unlikely the FCC would even bother with it.